# Looking for a method to statistically compare 2 3D structures

Tags: regression, correlation

G’day Statistics Forum
I’m having a little bit of trouble with the statistical analysis segment of my honors thesis proposal and was hoping one of you helpful folk might be able to offer some insight.
I believe this sounds more complex than it actually is, so bear with me cause I am really up the creek on this one.
I’m using remote sensing technology to derive a suite of data; I’m calling the ‘Detectable Physical Structure (DPS)’, for some trees. I’m also getting field measurements of the vegetation’s ‘Actual Physical Structure (APS)’.
Each tree has these 2 datasets and each of these datasets consists of 3D points representing the position of the trunk and branches that constitute the tree (a kind of 3D connect the dots).
Each of these subject points is given an identification number (Point_ID_1), the ‘X’, ‘Y’ and ‘Z’ values (equivalent to easting, northing and elevation respectively) and the next 3D point, or points, to which the subject point will connect upwardly.
(See attached diagram as I’ve probably described this simple concept terribly).
I’m looking to perform statistical analysis on a dataset of 20 - 40 trees (each with a sub-dataset of DPS and APS) to see how similar the DPS structure generally is to the APS and subsequently if there is a correlation between the two.
If my understanding of statistics is correct I need to generate some value to determine the accuracy of the DPS and run a regression analysis for the relationship between the DPS value and the APS value for each tree.
Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated, if my explanation is a little weak let me know and I’ll try to clarify it a bit better.
Regards
MattRNR

[image]

Comment: Could you explain why the $Y$ coordinates are missing from the figures and the tables? Is this a 3D problem or has it been reduced to a 2D one? Regardless, I suspect that for your question to be answerable you will need to explain more about your objectives. Exactly what factors matter when you compare a DPS to an APS? What kinds of errors can be incurred in your measurements?

Comment: My apologies I forgot to note that to compensate for my poor sketching ability I used a 2D representation but conceptually I imagine it will be the same.
In the simplest terms I’m trying to establish a relationship between the structure measured from actual trees and that derived by applying my algorithm to remotely sensed data.
The issue is predominantly that I need to find some way of comparing the 2 structures. The position of the 3D points is accurate to within about 10cm.

Comment: Ideally in doing so I’ll be able to apply the relationship to structures derived using only the algorithm.
Really appreciate any help you can provide.
Regards
MattRNR